# Fetch and upload files and prefixed files to s3 using perl

Tags: perl, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to fetch files from s3 using `Amazon::S3` module in Perl . I am successfully able to download files which are not prefixed but unable to fetch prefixed files like `test/abc.txt`.

I am using below code.

```
sub export_bucket {
  my ($conn, $bucket, $directory) = @_;
  $bucket = $conn->bucket($bucket);
  my $response = $bucket->list();
  print $response->{bucket}."\n";
  for my $key (@{ $response->{keys} }) {
        print "\t".$key->{key}."\n";  
        _export_file($conn,$bucket,$key->{key}, $directory.'/'.$key->{key});
  }
}

sub _export_file {
  my ($conn,$bucket,$name,$path) = @_;
  print "Downloading $name file","\n";
  my $test = $bucket->get_key_filename($name,'GET',$path);
  print Dumper($test);
  my $acl = $bucket->get_acl($name);
  print Dumper($acl);
  open my $acl_file, '>', $path.'.acl';
  print $acl_file $acl;
  close $acl_file;
}
```

Suggest me what changes should i make so that when a prefixed/folder comes i should be able to download the folder as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify you code to create the target directory on your local filesystem if it does not already exist. It should look something like this:

```
use File::Path qw[make_path];

sub export_bucket {
    my ( $conn, $bucket, $directory ) = @_;
    $bucket = $conn->bucket($bucket);
    my $response = $bucket->list();
    print $response->{bucket} . "\n";
    for my $key ( @{ $response->{keys} } ) {
        print "\t" . $key->{key} . "\n";
        _export_file( $conn, $bucket, $key->{key}, $directory . '/' . $key->{key} );
    }
}

sub _export_file {
    my ( $conn, $bucket, $name, $path ) = @_;
    print "Downloading $name file", "\n";
    my $test = $bucket->get_key_filename( $name, 'GET', $path );
    print Dumper($test);
    my $acl = $bucket->get_acl($name);
    print Dumper($acl);

    ## get path directory part
    my ($dir_part) = $path =~ /(.+)\/[^\/]+$/;

    unless ( -d $dir_part ) {
        make_path($dir_part);
    }

    open my $acl_file, '>', $path . '.acl';
    print $acl_file $acl;
    close $acl_file;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps $directory has a trailing "/" already in the case that is failing (or $key->{key} has a preceding slash)? Try debug-printing $directory and $path in the code to see exactly what your string arguments are.

Comment: $directory is directory where file will saved like /home/users/xyz/obs/ and $path will be /home/users/xyz/obs/test/readme-cron.txt where test/ is prefixed and readme-cron.txt is under this prefix in s3.

Comment: If $directory has a trailing slash like that, then your code will get a double-slash ("//") between "obs" and "test". Again, _print the $path variable to check this_.

Comment: these are the logged values their is no double slash between obs and test . test doesnt contain any preceding slash .